# PyQt: How to convert from Python to QDate style

Tags: python, pyqt

QtCore.QDate accepts three integers as arguments: year first, then month, then date. Example:

```
myDateEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(2015, 12, 28))
```

In order to "convert" QDate 'style' to Python use:

```
myPythonicDate=myDateEdit.date().toPyDate()
print myPythonicDate
'2014-04-17'
```

The question is:

```
# With a variable:

myPythonicDate='2014-04-17'
```

what syntax is used to declare QDate object... the following won't work:

```
myDateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate(myPythonicDate))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fromString` method of `QDate` will do the conversion for you:

```
myPythonicDate='2014-04-17'
qtDate = QtCore.QDate.fromString(myPythonicDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
print qtDate.year(), qtDate.month(), qtDate.day()
2014 4 17
```

`yyyy-MM-dd` is the format of your date; `yyyy` indicates a four digit year while `MM` and `dd` indicate month/date are two characters.  See the `fromString` documentation for a list of additional field options.

Comment: Is this the only way? I mean, converting to a string as an intermediate step is neither efficient nor concise.